# get value from input field and Append it as ul li a list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code i want to get Value from input field and then i want it to append it in unordered list as a anchor a tag basically i ant to create a list or you can say navbar item links i give input "home" and then append it and then input "about us" and append it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#btn2").click(function(){
               var v = $("#txt").val();
               $("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>",v,"</a></li>");

               });
          });
       </script>
     </head>
<body>
     <input id="txt" type="text">
     <ul>

     </ul>
     <button id="btn2">Append list items</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>"+v+"</a></li>");

Comment: not working your given ans

Comment: sorry my bad i didnt remove commas thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You were close, it looks like you just needed to replace `",v,"` with `" + v + "`

here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0ppc2mjs/

Comment: Was about to comment this and indeed this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need this

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>"+ v + "</a></li>");
```

Working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var v = $("#txt").val();
    $("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>"+ v + "</a></li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="txt" type="text">
  <ul>

  </ul>
  <button id="btn2">Append list items</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your support during my Front-end Developer position test

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>",v,"</a></li>");
```

to this

```
$("ul").append(`<li><a href='#'>${v}</a></li>`);
```

note: I changed your double quotes to back-ticks to enable string interpolation.